Entity in clean architecture. How is structured the entity layer of the clean architecture?
In clean architecture, should the entities in the entity layer interact with each other like in a class diagram or can they be independent of each other ?
I am trying to model the entity layer for an app, but i feel like i am forcing my entities into useless relationship
